# How to show EditText's time in TimePicker?

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker

how can I show the time which is already in EditText but I have to show the EditText set time in time picker. I try the code below but do not seem to be done yet.

```
var dateFormat = ""
    if (edittext?.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
        var date = edittext?.text?.trim().toString()
        var spf = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa")
        val newDate = spf.parse(date)
        spf = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")
        date = spf.format(newDate)
        dateFormat = date
    }

    val timeSetListener = OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hour, minute ->
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
        edittext?.setText(SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa").format(cal.time))
    }

    if (dateFormat.isNotEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            val finalDate: String = dateFormat
            val datearr = finalDate.split(":").toTypedArray()
            val hh = datearr[0].toInt()
            val mm = datearr[1].toInt()
            TimePickerDialog(activity, timeSetListener, hh, mm,false).show()
        }
        catch (e: Exception)
        {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val yy = calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]
            val mm = calendar[Calendar.MINUTE]
            TimePickerDialog(activity, timeSetListener, yy, mm, false).show()
        }
        catch (e: java.lang.Exception)
        {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Please check this code and help. In addition, I have to do this with *am* and *pm* so that is not the main issue .

Answer (score 0):

"time" is your EditText component try this code... Happy Coding:)

```
time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar selectedHour = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (!TextUt.isEmpty(time.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    Date d = null;
                    try {
                        d = sdf2.parse(date.getText().toString());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    selectedHour.setTime(d);
                    selectedHour.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString().split(":")[0]));
                    selectedHour.set(MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString().split(":")[1]));
                }
                TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
                        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                        try {
                            Date d = sdf2.parse(date.getText().toString());
                            c1.setTime(d);
                            c1.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                            c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                            c2.setTime(d);
                            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(time.getText().toString())) {
                                c2.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                                c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                            } else {
                                  c2.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(starts[0]));
                                c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(starts[1]));
                            }

                            Calendar controlCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            controlCalendar.setTime(d);
                            controlCalendar.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                            controlCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                            time.setText(String.format("%02d", hour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minute));
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, selectedHour.get(HOUR_OF_DAY), selectedHour.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
                dialog.show();
```